# How to fix: Undefined undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 - libdl.so missing from CL

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, libdl

I've been porting this code to work with opencv3. 
https://github.com/anhttran/extreme_3d_faces

So far I have made it through most of the compilation but I keep getting this error when its almost complete. I have looked at a number of occurances of this issue but none of the solutions have worked for me as yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So far I've tried:

- creating the symbolic link to libdl.so manually (as this solved a few similar errors I had earlier in the compliation)
- adding -ldl as a flag, and in the cmakelists
- rearranging the order of the included libraries as that has been known to have an effect

Result:

```
[ 92%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/TestBump /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libhdf5.a(H5PL.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status config/CMakeFiles/TestBump.dir/build.make:149: recipe for target 'bin/TestBump'
failed make[2]: *** [bin/TestBump] Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:196: recipe for target 'config/CMakeFiles/TestBump.dir/all'
failed make[1]: *** [config/CMakeFiles/TestBump.dir/all] Error 2 
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So far nothing has worked.
any advice?

The code in my cmakelists file is as follows.

```
# Local libraries
include_directories(../modules/CvGl)
include_directories(../modules/PoseExpr/include)
include_directories(${DLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
add_definitions(-DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT)
add_definitions(-DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} 
"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
SET(SOURCE
    ../main.cpp
)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-w -fopenmp")
add_executable(TestBump ${SOURCE})

if(WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(TestBump ${OpenCVLibraries})
endif(WIN32)
if(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(TestBump -ldl ${OpenCV_LIBS} 
${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
endif(UNIX)
target_link_libraries(TestBump PoseExprLib 
${DLIB_LIB_DIR}/libdlib.so  ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} -lGLU -lOSMesa -lm)
install (TARGETS TestBump DESTINATION .)
```

Comment: Do you have the correct version of libdl installed? The unresolved symbol has a version name mangled into it.

Comment: Since you have `libhdf5` as a *static* library, whenever you use this library you need to link with `dl` **manually**. In CMake linking is performed with `target_link_libraries` call, which is noted in none of your attempts. Duplicate question (and answer to it) describes how to link with `dl` library in CMake.

Comment: @Mansoor: The error message `DSO missing from command line` with the exact path to the library always means that given library is simply **not linked**. This error has nothing common with libraries *incompatibility*.

Comment: Hi there, 

libdl was installed as part of libboost-all/libc6-dev and it worked before in the docker implementation of this code, when compling with opencv2 libs - unfortunately it doesnt support my GPU though so Im compiling with opencv3 - I havent had this error during other cmake operations.

I've tried setting the target-libraries in the correct CMake list file (added to the orig post) but still receive the same error - I'd already tried the solution suggested in that answer.